# Как работает код счетчика метрики?

Tags: javascript, yandex-metrika-api, яндекс-метрика

Стало интересно как работает код счетчика метрики, но в JavaScript я не очень силен, знакомился с ним буквально по верхам.

```
(function(d, w, c) {
(w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
    try {
        w.yaCounterCOUNTER_ID = new Ya.Metrika({
            id: COUNTER_ID,
            clickmap: true,
            trackLinks: true,
            accurateTrackBounce: true,
            webvisor: true
        });
    } catch (e) {}
});
var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
    s = d.createElement("script"),
    f = function() {
        n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n);
    };
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.async = true;
s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";
if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
    d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
} else {
    f();
}
})(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
```

Не очень ясна конструкция в самом начале функции. Каким образом будет создан новый объект `Ya.Metrika`, если его фактически в коде нет, а сам скрипт `watch.js` подгружается в коде позже?

И как здесь все-таки работает добавление самого скрипта `watch.js`? Ведь если посмотреть код страницы с установленным счетчиком, тег `script` с параметрами и путем к `watch.js` не будет виден в коде страницы.

Заранее спасибо за объяснения!

Comment: для тех кто найдет это  - предполагаю, что код уже совсем не такой и этот должен быть заменен на тот.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Отличный вопрос! Давайте по-порядку:

### 1. Объявление и вызов главной функции

```
(function(d, w, c) {
  ...
})(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
```

Здесь вы объявляете некую функцию, и сразу после объявления - ее же и вызываете с параметрами `document`, `window` и строковым ключом Яндекс.Метрики. Эти параметры используются внутри функции.

### 2. Сохранение конструктора метрики

```
w[c] = w[c] || []
```

`w` - это ваше окно браузера. В нем вы можете хранить функции или данные, и они будут доступны глобально в других скриптах. По сути, здесь вы обращаетесь к `w["yandex_metrika_callbacks"]`, и там либо уже будут какие-то значения (например, с других счетчиков Яндекс.Метрики), либо объявленный вами пустой массив.

```
.push(function() {
  ...
);
```

И далее в этот массив (уже существующий или только что созданный) вы добавляете элемент - функцию, которая попытается создать объект счетчика метрики.

```
w.yaCounterCOUNTER_ID = new Ya.Metrika({
  ..
});
```

Создаете объект снова у окна `w`, чтобы он был доступен в любых других скриптах.

### 3. Асинхронная загрузка скрипта метрики

```
n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
```

Здесь вы находите первый попавшийся у вас на сайте тег `<script>`. Метрике это нужно, чтобы вот этой командой..

```
n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n);
```

..вставить новый созданный ею скрипт перед вашим имеющимся. Перед или после - не имеет значения, главное поместить скрипт на страницу, и метрика делает это гарантированным способом.

> Можно было бы помещать скрипт в конец `<body>` или `<head>`, но эти теги с недавних пор в верстке необязательны. А вот тег `<script>` у вас на сайте будет однозначно хотя бы один - с кодом счетчика метрики.

```
s = d.createElement("script")
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.async = true;
s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";
```

Здесь метрика как раз создает тот тег `<script>`, который потом вставит в страницу, и после вставки скрипт начнет асинхронно загружаться.

```
f();
```

Вот здесь это и происходит, вызывается функция f, которая вставляет тег `<script>` метрики в DOM. Чуть выше видно исключение, в случае, если используется браузер Opera:

```
d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
```

Которое точно так же выполнит функцию f, но после полной загрузки DOM'а браузером.

### 4. Выполнение асинхронно загруженного скрипта

В итоге у вас асинхронно загружается скрипт `watch.js`, а в `window["yandex_metrika_callbacks"]` у вас хранятся функции-конструкторы объектов Яндекс.Метрики.

Когда скрипт `watch.js` загрузится, он просто вызовет все эти функции подряд, инициализировав таким образом все счетчики Яндекс.Метрики, которые вы захотели видеть на сайте.

Comment: Отличный ответ! :)
А Вы могли бы дать наводку на информацию о том, как хранить функции в объекте window? Покопался на learn.javascript.ru, но не нашел информации. Нашел общие слова об объекте и методах.

Comment: @kover-samolet, здесь нужно подумать о том, зачем вам нужны глобальные функции? И сколько таких функций вам нужно? Хорошей практикой считается по возможности избегать глобальных объектов и функций, а если и хранить их - то в виде толстых объектов, вмещающих в себя все нужные функции для работы с чем-то конкретным. Например редактор CKEditor хранит все свои данные и функции в `window.CKEDITOR`, и именно через него в своих скриптах вы можете работать с редактором.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Буду думать :)

Comment: `<body>` и `<head>` необязательны в *вёрстке*. Но в DOM они всё равно будут гарантированно присутствовать, поэтому `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` всегда что-то вернёт.

Answer (score 5):

Конструкция в начале не создает обЪект *Ya.Metrika*, как в верно заметили, на этом этапе его еще нет. Этак конструкция лишь добавляет в массив *window. yandex_metrika_callbacks* функцию, которая должна создать этот объект. А сама эта функция вызывается в скрипте **watch.js**, когда объект *Ya.Metrika* уже создан.

На счет добавления скрипта **watch.js**:
Он добавляется динамически перед первым тегом *script* на странице в данный момент. Если вы смотрите код страницы через *view page source*, то вы его естественно там не увидите, вам нужно воспользоваться инструментом разработчика в браузере (что бы ее открыть, можно кликнуть по странице правой кнопкой и выбрать пункт *inspect element*).